# pasting in a loop to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need someone who is an excel master to show me how to copy a column with 90,596 rows from one excel spreadsheet and paste it into another spreadsheet where it will start in row two of the first column go down to row 105 then loop back up to row 2 in the next column and continue doing so until all values have been transferred.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with a Visual Basic script or you could use the INDEX, ROW and COLUMN functions to copy and re-arrange the data, as follows:

Assumption: Your original data is on a worksheet called Sheet1, in a single column, starting at cell A2.

Method:

- On a new worksheet, put the following formula in cell A2:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,ROW()+(105*(COLUMN()-1)))`

- This should show the first value of your original data.
- 'Drag fill' the formula down to cell A106 and you should now see the first 105 values of your original data.
- 'Drag fill' the still selected range across to cell AGE106 and you will see the rest of the original data spanning 863 columns, each 105 rows high. The last few rows of the last column will be filled with zeros that are not part of your original data. You can delete these manually if you wish.

You're now left with a live 'table' of your original data. If you change values in the original data, the table version will also update. If you'd like to 'disconnect' the two, you can copy the table to the clipboard and then Paste Special -> As Values.